# execute function when 3 or more booleans become true angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following code: my task is to check if 4 or more of these buttons are selected, and if they are, i need to display a custom message with something like "you can select only 3 filters". Please note that i need to execute this function BEFORE the button that launches the research, so i need Angular to constantly check for those boolean values as the user activates and deactivates the buttons. I tried using $watch and ng-change, but they didn't work as expected.

How can i do that? Hope i made myself clear, thanks in advance, feel free to ask if you need clarifications.

HTML and controller logic here:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn"
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="smsFilter =! smsFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': smsFilter == true}">Sms</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="videoChatFilter =! videoChatFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': videoChatFilter == true}">Video Chat</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="chatFilter =! chatFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': chatFilter == true}">Chat</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">

            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn"
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="socialFilter =! socialFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': socialFilter == true}">Social</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="emailFilter =! emailFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': emailFilter == true}">Email</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="telefonateFilter =! telefonateFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': telefonateFilter == true}">Telefonate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn"
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="formTicketFilter =! formTicketFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': formTicketFilter == true}">Form Ticket</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="chatOfferFilter =! chatOfferFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': chatOfferFilter == true}">Chat Offer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="bannerFilter =! bannerFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': bannerFilter == true}">Banner</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn"
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="webFilter =! webFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': webFilter == true}">Web</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="agenziaFilter =! agenziaFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': agenziaFilter == true}">Agenzia</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default filterBtn "
                style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
                ng-click="crcFilter =! crcFilter"
                ng-class="{'active': crcFilter == true}">CRC</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="btn btn-default headerBtn" style="margin-top: 10px;" ng-click="applyFilters()">Apply Filters</button>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
    //FILTERS
    $scope.smsFilter = false;
    $scope.videoChatFilter = false;
    $scope.chatFilter = false;
    $scope.socialFilter = false;
    $scope.emailFilter = false;
    $scope.telefonateFilter = false;
    $scope.formTicketFilter = false;
    $scope.chatOfferFilter = false;
    $scope.webFilter = false;
    $scope.agenziaFilter = false;
    $scope.crcFilter = false;

//function that executes the research
$scope.applyFilters = function(){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<p ng-show="videoChatFilter+chatFilter+socialFilter+emailFilter+telefonateFilter+formTicketFilter+chatOfferFilter+webFilter+agenziaFilter+crcFilter > 3">You can only select up to 3 filters</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, though I don't know about performance, however. Test it first.

```
var filtersArray = [/*PUT YOUR FILTERS IN HERE AS WELL*/];
$scope.$watch(function(){
    var trueFilters = filtersArray.filter(function(f){ return f === true;});
    return trueFilters.length > 3;
}, function(_old, _new){
    if(!_new) return;
    //Do something when they are true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create common Object with properties that related to each filter and use `ng-if="isFilterSelected('smsFilter', 'videoChatFilter')"` for your message block.

In your controller it will be something like

`$scope.isFilterSelected = function () {
    var filtersToCheck = angular.copy(arguments);
    return _.chain($scope.filters)
               .filter(function(value, name){
                   return _.contains(filtersToCheck, name);
               })
               .every(_.identity)
               .value();
}`

I hope you are using some **underscore** or **lodash** in your... application.